# Problema con el inicio de sesion con Google en Firebase

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

buen día.
Tengo en mi aplicación un inicio de sesión con Google en Firebase, mi aplicación ya está subida en play store.
El problema está en que cuando la instalo desde play store no funciona el inicio de sesión con Google. Pero probé pasando por usb el apk generado al almacenamiento de mi celular y instalar la app desde ahí y funciona perfecto.

Estoy usando estos permisos:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Y también agregue los sha1 a mi proyecto en firebase.

Por favor ayuda, no se que mas intentar.

Comment: Seguramente no estas haciendo la firma correctamente, agregaste tanto la huella del `keystore` y la huella para debug de android studio?

Comment: Gracias! lo pude solucionar, me faltaba vincular mi aplicación de firebase a google play.

Comment: Se hace de esta forma: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6392038?hl=es-419

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que la configuración de Firebase está vinculada al SHA que se genera para tu app de desarrollo ( el que agregaste al momento de sumar la app en la consola de Firebase).

Para solucionarlo simplemente tienes que agregar el SHA de tu app en play store en la **consola de Firebase > configuración de proyecto** y en la app Android agregar el SHA que corresponde a tu app productiva.

Puede ser el que generaste al firmar el APK original al momento de hacer el build o en caso de usar el servicio de analisis y refirma de APK de Google Play encontrarás el SHA que necesitas en la **consola de Google Play > Release Management > App Signing**

Answer (score 1):

A mi también me faltaba vincular mi aplicación de firebase a google play.

Consola de firebase, Configuración, Integraciones: y vincular Google Play